# Moving expectation into probability

Tags: self-study, expected-value

Let $ F(g), Y $ be a random variables with finite expected values. Then, we define $ X(g) $ as:

$$
    X(g) := \left\{
            \begin{array}{ll}
                1, & \quad \text{if } F(g) + Y > 0 \\
                0, & \quad \text{else.}
            \end{array}
        \right.  
$$

Is it true that $ \mathbb{E} [ X(g) ] = \text{Pr} [\mathbb{E}[F(g)] + \mathbb{E}[Y] > 0]$?

Comment: That seems to be correct.

Comment: @Marius I'm not sure I follow your logic. How does that lead to the equality I asked about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expectation of the random variable is the function of parameters, and is not random variable anymore. So Pr{E(...)>0} does not exist.

Comment: Instead of "does not exist" I would say the probability $P(\textrm{constant}>0)$ exists and equals either $0$ or $1$... (formalized as $P(\{\omega \in \Omega \mid \textrm{constant} > 0\})$, this is either $P(\emptyset)$ or $P(\Omega)$ depending on the constant).

Answer (score 1):

Using the law of total probability, 
$$ \mathbb{E} [ X(g) ] = \text{P}(\mathbb{F(g) + Y > 0})$$  There should not be any expectations inside the probability.